# Authorization of rest api using OAuth2.0

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, authorization, jwt

I am developing a REST API using node js and express js. 
For example, my RESTful API end points are as follows

```
/api/v1/books/:id
/api/v1/books
```

I want to authorize the end points only for specific application(web, android or ios).

**The users of the application may or may not authenticate in the application.

```
ex: www.bookstore.com
bookstore android/ios app
```

ie. only these applications can have access to those end points.
How can I implement this using OAuth 2.0 and JWT

For example we can view every item in amazon(web/android/ios) without providing login credentials.

How can this be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jwt and Oauth is used for user authentication and authorization. Here, I believe you want only specific clients to have access to your APIs. For this purpose you may use joi validator available on npm registry.
npm install joi.
Now provide a schema for your app type and make it required.

Comment: Not specific clients. All the clients using my application only can access my backend API.  And the JOI is used for input validation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by specific clients.. Ur front-end can send the application type and version to server where you can verify using JOI. Else you may use access-control-allow-origin header to allow only one domain to access your backend. This is in no way related to Oauth (as far as my knowledge goes). I would suggest that you use both CORS and JOI.

Answer (score 0):

The flow that you describe is a typical "[**client credentials** grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4)":

> The client credentials (or other forms of client authentication) can
> be used as an authorization grant when the authorization scope is
> limited to the protected resources under the control of the client,
> ....  Client credentials are used as an authorization grant
> typically **when the client is acting on its own behalf (the client is
>
> also the resource owner)** ...

in this use case, the end-user is not required to login, only the client-id, which is your app.